# Sitecore 8 Speak UI - Call Pagecode Javascript from HTMLTemplate link

Tags: javascript, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-speak-ui

I am working on ListControl and one of the columns has Delete link which I am formatting using HTMLTemplate as follows:

```
<a href="javascript: app.showConfirmation()" >Delete</a>
```

My Javascript looks as follows:

```
define(["sitecore", function (Sitecore) {
  var DestinationRules = Sitecore.Definitions.App.extend({
      initialized: function () {
          this.processDestinationRules();
      },
      showConfirmation: function () {
          alert('here');

      },

  });

  return DestinationRules;
});
```

For some reason, I am not able to call showConfirmation(). It says is undefined. I even tried Sitecore.Speak.app.showconfirmation() but not working.

I tried my best to search online but not able to find much help around calling function through controls embedded inside HTMLTemplate.

My next step is to call DialogWindow.

Please if you can help me with the syntax of the above. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, managed to do this. Always knew that it can be done this way but did not like the way its done.

The Delete link in List control opens up a confirmation Dialogue window. And if user selects Yes then it calls the `app.onDeleteYes()`

The HtmlMarkup for the column:

```
<a href="javascript:destinationRulePage.showDeleteDialog({{itemId}});">Delete</a>
```

Added a button called `btnDelete` with `visibility` set to `false`.

Added following function, outside the scope of App:

```
var destinationRulePage = (function () {
    var self = this;
    self.showDeleteDialog = function (id) {
        $("button[data-sc-id='btnYes']").attr("data-sc-click",
            "javascript:app.onDeleteYes(" + id + ");");
        $("button[data-sc-id='btnDelete']").click();
    }
    return self;
}())
```

This does the job for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it in a different way.

I wanted to show in-line Delete button in each row of the Listcontrol. Could not figure out way to call the

```
javascript: app.showConfirmation()
```

I changed the way to delete the record:

- Have one Delete button outside the ListControl.
- Enable/Disable the Delete button based on binding ListControl.HasSelectedItem.
- On click of the Delete button, call showConfirmation()

As of now seems to be a better way. Sitecore itself uses similar approach for "Kicking off" users. Can be found here:

```
/sitecore/client/Applications/LicenseOptions/KickUser
```

Hope that helps. Thanks.